# Insert an object at certain position in an object of javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a main JavaScript object and I would like to add another object to it at a specific location.

Main object

```
const table = {
  general: {
    title: "general",    
    fields: [
     {
      type: "Input",
      model: "name"
     },
     {
      type: "Input",
      model: "networkDeviceMake"
     },
    {
      type: "Select",
      model: "networkDeviceStatus"
    }
  ]
 },
 location: {
   title: "location",
   fields: [
   {
     type: "Select",
     model: "locationType"
   },
   {
     type: "Input",
     model: "Floor"
   },
   {
     type: "Input",
     model: "Description"
   }
  ]
 },
};
```

Second object

```
const section = {
  after: "general",
  section: {
    plans: {
      title: "plans",
      fields: [
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planA",
        },
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planB",
        },
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planC",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

In this case, I would like to add the second object after the **general** key

The result should look like this

```
{
  general: {
    title: "general",    
    fields: [
      {
        type: "Input",
        model: "name"
      },
      {
        type: "Input",
        model: "networkDeviceMake"
      },
      {
        type: "Select",
        model: "networkDeviceStatus"
      }
    ]
  },
  plans: {
      title: "plans",
      fields: [
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planA",
        },
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planB",
        },
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planC",
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  location: {
    title: "location",
    fields: [
      {
        type: "Select",
        model: "locationType"
      },
      {
        type: "Input",
        model: "Floor"
      },
      {
        type: "Input",
        model: "Description"
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

You will notice that in the second object I provide the key **after** that I want to use to determine where the second object should be added to the main object.

I understand that using `main = Object.assign(main, second)` will result in the second object being added at the end of the main and that is not my objective.

Cheers.

Update:
The order matters in regards to how it will be implemented and the implementation can not be changed. The second object will be handed into a function and from there I expect we would need to iterate over the main object and then add the second object at the appropriate point.

Solution:

I ended up going with Robin's solution of using a spread operator.

```
  table = {
      general: table.general,
      plans: section.section.plans,
      ...table
    };
```

Doing it this way meant that I had to manually create the new object because I would have to know in advance the name of the object keys and where to insert the second object.

The ideal solution would be to hand the second object to a function and let the function determine how to construct the new object without knowing in advance what the names of the keys would be and where to insert the second object. The function would have to use the key **after** in the second object to determine where to perform the insert; perhaps via the use of a spread operator.

Comment: Object keys order are not guaranteed

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/23202095#23202095 Also, the fact that you're calling it `table` is a powerful hint that you would want an array of arrays structure

Comment: ```In this case, I would like to add the second object after the general key``` why do you want to achieve this? If you want to get the value of an object you can access it like object[key], the ordering of the key in the object doesn't matter. However, if the ordering matters, why don't you use array structure instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the inner property's order.

```js
const table = {
  general: {
    title: "general",
    fields: [{
        type: "vfgAdminTextInput",
        model: "name"
      },
      {
        type: "vfgAdminTextInput",
        model: "networkDeviceMake"
      },
      {
        type: "Select",
        model: "networkDeviceStatus"
      }
    ]
  },
  location: {
    title: "location",
    fields: [{
        type: "Select",
        model: "locationType"
      },
      {
        type: "Input",
        model: "Floor"
      },
      {
        type: "Input",
        model: "Description"
      }
    ]
  },
};

const section = {
  after: "general",
  section: {
    plans: {
      title: "plans",
      fields: [{
          type: "select",
          model: "planA",
        },
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planB",
        },
        {
          type: "select",
          model: "planC",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

const main = {
  general: table.general,
  plans: section.section,
  location: table.location
}

console.log(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator but as mentioned above why does the order matter?

Worth reading this too https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/

```js
const table = {
  general: {
    title: "general",
    fields: [{
      type: "vfgAdminTextInput",
      model: "name"
    }, {
      type: "vfgAdminTextInput",
      model: "networkDeviceMake"
    }, {
      type: "Select",
      model: "networkDeviceStatus"
    }]
  },
  location: {
    title: "location",
    fields: [{
      type: "Select",
      model: "locationType"
    }, {
      type: "Input",
      model: "Floor"
    }, {
      type: "Input",
      model: "Description"
    }]
  },
};

const section = {
  after: "general",
  section: {
    plans: {
      title: "plans",
      fields: [{
        type: "select",
        model: "planA",
      }, {
        type: "select",
        model: "planB",
      }, {
        type: "select",
        model: "planC",
      }]
    }
  }
};

let newObj = {
  'general': table.general,
  'plans': section.section.plans,
  ...table
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 4));
```

Comment: Cheers for that . Also the order matters in regards to how it will be implemented, and the implementation can not be changed.

Comment: The second object will be handed in to a function and from there I expect we would need to iterate over the main object and then add the second object at the appropriate point.